# Dropdownlist value not getting set from SelectList passed to view in ViewData

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, null, viewdata, selectlist

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist of office locations(text) and addresses (value)
When viewing my page source in my browser after displaying the page I can see that the select (dropdownlist)  option values are all "". Here is my code. I am using a LinqToSql data context call to get my data for the SelectList. In the debugger I can see that the list returned from my call does in fact have the addresses and office locations I need.
My model datacontext code:

```
public partial class uls_dbDataContext
{
    public List<office_location> GetOfficeLocations()
    {
        return office_locations.ToList();
    }
}
```

My controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Directions()
    {
        uls_dbDataContext ulsdb_dc = new uls_dbDataContext();

        ViewData["OfficeLocations"] = new SelectList(ulsdb_dc.GetOfficeLocations(),"location_address", "location_name");

        ViewData["Title"] = "Directions";

        return View();
    }
```

My view code:
         <%= Html.DropDownList("locations", (SelectList)ViewData["OfficeLocations"])%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade to MVC RC2 from preview 4. It addressed drodownlist issues and fixed my problem.